# miss wifi hardware driver

Tags: drivers, wireless, broadcom

After upgrading from 14.xx.xx to 16.04 I miss the wifi.

Herewith is the nice report... so... anybody has a clue about what I should do now?

Thank you in advance.

```
dmesg | grep -i firmware
[   14.893895] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-0b05-17b5.hcd failed with error -2
[   15.436254] b43 bcma0:1: Direct firmware load for b43/ucode30_mimo.fw failed with error -2
[   15.436293] b43 bcma0:1: Direct firmware load for b43/ucode30_mimo.fw failed with error -2
[   15.436326] b43 bcma0:1: Direct firmware load for b43-open/ucode30_mimo.fw failed with error -2
[   15.436350] b43 bcma0:1: Direct firmware load for b43-open/ucode30_mimo.fw failed with error -2
[   15.436358] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43/ucode30_mimo.fw" not found
[   15.436364] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43-open/ucode30_mimo.fw" not found
[   15.436368] b43-phy0 ERROR: You must go to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware and download the correct firmware for this driver version.
     Please carefully read all instructions on this website.
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me finding the thread that fits. Following the instructions found here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx the computer now sees the wifi but isn't still working... I will continue trying anyway, there are 46 answers to go through, the first is done! 45 to go. :-)

Comment: Did you install the firmware? What does this tell us now? `dmesg | grep b43`?